# How to hide the sliding menu on pressing back or while opening an activity

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

I am using this library, i would like to hide the sliding-menu when i open an new `activity`, so that when i press back i don't want the sliding menu to appear.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.Home");
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        break;
   }
}
```

The above code is in my `SherlockListFragment` class, i would like to hide the sliding-menu, once i start a new activity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you've extended SlidingActivity, then all you need is:-

```
toggle();
```

That should do it :-)

Comment: I need to call this method toggle from my fragment class and not from activity... thats where i am stuck... thanks

Comment: Could you post some more code, so we can see the setup? Else, getActivity().toggle() springs to mind.

Comment: Ryan:: Here is my complete code... http://pastie.org/private/5het0nrgp0h5wmiziqcnma

Comment: Kevin, how are you instantiating the menu. Is it attached to an Activity or is it in code? If it's in the Activity hosting that Fragment then you getActivity().showContent() to make sure it's closed.  If you instantiated in code then you can call mySlidingMenu.showContent() to close. If you know it's open, toggle() could be used. Sorry, just can't see where it is from the pasted code.

Comment: Not sure why you couldn't call showContent() from your Fragment? E.g.((BaseActivity)getActivity()).showContent();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28062/discussion-between-kevin-and-ryan)

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {   
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.Home");
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        // Toggle the sliding menu
        ((YourHostActivity) getActivity()).getSlidingMenu().toggle();
        break;
   }
}
```

In your activity that hosts the sliding menu:

```
public onCreate(...) {
    // save the slidingmenu instance to a propery
    mSlidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
}

// create a getter
public SlidingMenu getSlidingMenu() {
    return mSlidingMenu;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you replaced `YourHostActivity` with your actual activity class.